# Testing for string containing variable characters in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, testing, variables, character

can i do something like this?

```
string = "123" + rand(10).to_s + "abc"
=> "1237abc"
string.include?("123" + string.any_character(1) + "abc") # any_character(digit)
=> true
```

the point is to know a part of a string like lets say a html tag string, testing for something like  Name Changes Every Day

and easily find the title from the source every time no matter what it might be, but for me, it will always be one character, soooooo, any help here?

Answer (score 0):

Try that code:

```
string = "123" + rand(10).to_s + "abc"
string =~ /123\dabc/
```

0 means that pattern starts at 0 character. This return nil when pattern doesnt match. If you want to match only whole text change `/123\dabc/` into `/^123\dabc$/`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [regular expressions](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html) with ruby. Example:

```
string = "123" + rand(10).to_s + "abc"
string.match /123\dabc/
```